# Como implementar um arquivo github no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Gostaria de implementar [esse arquivo](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) no `Android Studio` é só ir no importar ou tem que importar um arquivo específico.

Answer (score 1):

apliquei aqui nesse caso e ficou assim:
primeiro adicionei a dependência no gradle(build.gradle(Module app)), como descrito no "README"

```
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
```

depois peguei o exemplo da pasta sample:

o XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="input_hi"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="There's a lady who's sure all that glitters is gold
And she's buying a stairway to heaven" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="label_normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="example"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="label_autofit" />

    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/output_autofit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="example"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        autofit:minTextSize="8sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

e a MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mOutput, mAutofitOutput;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    mAutofitOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_autofit);

    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.input)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            mOutput.setText(charSequence);
            mAutofitOutput.setText(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
  }
}
```

e ficou assim:
O primeiro esta normal e embaixo com autofit

[image: O primeiro esta normal e embaixo com autofit]

Comment: mas como você importou para seu projeto no Android Studio?

Comment: Então, eu não dei import em nada, abri os códigos direto no github  quando você adiciona a linha no gradle e da um "sync" ele já adiciona as dependências necessárias para você utilizar o autofit,  e aqui funcionou como mostrado na imagem.

Comment: Você abriu o exemplo entendi mas Como importar para um outro  projeto  essa é a dúvida.

Comment: Achei que você só queria essa funcionabilidade do projeto do github funcionando no seu projeto, aí seria como eu te mostrei pelo meu projeto.

Comment: no caso é só copiar esse código dentro do projeto ?

Comment: Sim, foi o que eu fiz para testar, eu dei uma olhada por cima ontem e tem outro layout lá no projeto do github mas não coloquei no meu exemplo,  fiz o teste só com o xml e a activity principal, como mostrei, para ver funcionando já que também não conhecia. E não esquece de adicionar o compile no gradle do seu projeto